# Dynamic scatter plot from JSON data

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, json

I need to do a scatter plot of big data coming from R statistical package. I will convert the data to JSON. I will need to zoom in and out of the data and also pick on the data and get back the info about the point I picked. The plot will be annotated with lines (would like line-width and line-color attributes). This will be presented in browsers so javascript, jquery and css3 are ok.

Any suggestions on which javascript library is best suited for the job?

Answer (score 2):

As with most JavaScript visualizations, you can use the JavaScript library [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) (BSD license), it contains some function to:

- [draw a scatterplot](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887118)

[image]

- [display information about the point you picked](http://bl.ocks.org/weiglemc/6185069)

[image]

- [Drag + Zoom](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708)
- If the scatterplot takes too long to load because of the size of the data, you can use [progressive rendering](http://bl.ocks.org/syntagmatic/raw/3341641/).

Comment: Will d3.js support a million points? Are there any speed tests that I can consult?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. When this would be to simply take the code from the link in my answer and add a million points in the CSV list. Also, you can use [progressive rendering](http://bl.ocks.org/syntagmatic/raw/3341641/).